# How to do outer joins : Spark Scala SQLContext

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I am trying to get Total(count of all) and Top Elements (count after filters) so that I can find the percentile for each placeName in all jsons (top/total) with rating > 3 :

```
  // sc : An existing SparkContext.
    val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
    val df = sqlContext.jsonFile("temp.txt")
    //df.show()


    val res =  df.withColumn("visited", explode($"visited"))

    val result = res.groupBy($"customerId", $"visited.placeName")

Tried with joins :
val result1 =res.groupBy($"customerId", $"visited.placeName").agg(count("*").alias("total"))

val result2 = res
.filter($"visited.rating" < 4)
  .groupBy($"requestId", $"visited.placeName")  
  .agg(count("*").alias("top"))

result1.show()

result2.show()
percentile = result1.join(result2, List("placeName","customerId"), "outer")
 sqlContext.sql("select top/total as percentile from temp groupBy placeName")
```

but gives me error.

Can I do this in udf something like :

```
 val result1 =  result.withColumn("Top", getCount(res , true))
                    .withColumn("Total",getCount(result, false)).show()


    def getCount(df: DataFrame, flag: Boolean): Int {
            if (flag == "true") return df.filter($"visited.rating" < 3).groupBy($"customerId", $"visited.placeName").agg(count("*"))
            else return  df.agg(count("*"))
          }
```

My Schema :

```
 {
        "country": "France",
        "customerId": "France001",
        "visited": [
            {
                "placeName": "US",
                "rating": "2",
                "famousRest": "N/A",
                "placeId": "AVBS34"

            },
              {
                "placeName": "US",
                "rating": "3",
                "famousRest": "SeriousPie",
                "placeId": "VBSs34"

            },
              {
                "placeName": "Canada",
                "rating": "3",
                "famousRest": "TimHortons",
                "placeId": "AVBv4d"

            }        
    ]
}

US top = 1 count = 3
Canada top = 1 count = 3


{
        "country": "Canada",
        "customerId": "Canada012",
        "visited": [
            {
                "placeName": "UK",
                "rating": "3",
                "famousRest": "N/A",
                "placeId": "XSdce2"

            },


    ]
}
UK top = 1 count = 1


{
        "country": "France",
        "customerId": "France001",
        "visited": [
            {
                "placeName": "US",
                "rating": "4.3",
                "famousRest": "N/A",
                "placeId": "AVBS34"

            },
              {
                "placeName": "US",
                "rating": "3.3",
                "famousRest": "SeriousPie",
                "placeId": "VBSs34"

            },
              {
                "placeName": "Canada",
                "rating": "4.3",
                "famousRest": "TimHortons",
                "placeId": "AVBv4d"

            }        
    ]
}

US top = 2 count = 3
Canada top = 1 count = 3
```

So at the end I need something like :

```
PlaceName  percentile
US         57.14            (1+1+2)/(3+1+3) *100
Canada     33.33            (1+1)/(3+3) *100
UK         100               1*100
```

Schema:

```
root
|-- country: string(nullable=true)
|-- customerId:string(nullable=true)
|-- visited: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |   |-- placeId: string (nullable = true)
|    |   |-- placeName: string (nullable = true) 
|    |   |-- famousRest: string (nullable = true)
|    |   |-- rating: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 2):

Given a code you provided it is not clear how the source is structured and why you get this particular error but in general this code is not even remotely valid.

- `getCount` is not an UDF - not crucial but important distinction.
- `getCount` is not a valid function because there is no `col` type in the scope. Unless you for some reason use this as a type alias for `o.a.s.sql.DataFrame` this wouldn't even compile!
- Even if types matched Spark doesn't support nested actions / transformations so you cannot use UDF to execute query or aggregation on Spark `DataFrame`.

Comment: I was just trying to add what I intended to do. I  tried with separate queries and use joins : val res =  df.withColumn("visited", explode($"visited"))

`val result1 =res.groupBy($"customerId", $"visited.placeName").agg(count("*").alias("total"))

val result2 = res
.filter($"visited.rating" < 4)
  .groupBy($"requestId", $"visited.placeName")  
  .agg(count("*").alias("top"))

result1.show()

result2.show() `

Comment: and use joins : `percentile  = result1.join(result2, List("placeName","customerId"), "outer")  sqlContext.sql("select top/total as percentile from temp groupBy placeName")` But it gives error as well. That why wanted to try pdf (to add the counts (top and total) . Can you let me know how do I approach this to get the percentile